# Browsing and upload file in ASP.net / Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

From the Page, user can browse and select a folder on their local drive. after selection it populate list of file names in listbox.

Then I will use these file paths randomly to upload to server.

Is this possible?

I am asking because what i know due to security browser prevent to access client files.

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML5 File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) might contain something you can use to accomplish your goal, but then your application will only work with browsers that implement that API.